# Python BeautifulSoup - get onmouseover attributes

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to get the javascript function name from tags that contain attribute "onmouseover". For example :

```
<p onmouseover="test_hover2()" />Title<p>
<img src="esel.png" onmouseover="test_hover()" id="logo" />
```

I tried :

```
for tag in soup.findAll(onmouseover=True):
    print tag.onmouseover
```

I wanting the result as "test_hover2(),test_hover()". But it return None

What could I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
tag['onmouseover']
```

HTML attributes translate to keys in BS objects in Python. Attributes of BS objects are HTML children. Hope that makes sense ...

Comment: You really save my day :D. Thanks a alot.

Comment: I've made the same mistake more times than I want to admit :)